# JAR File in Installation folder

Tags: executable-jar, install4j

We have used install 4j for converting jar to exe/dmg installation. But the installation directory is including even jar file and exe file. How can we hide the jar file in the installation directory using install 4j?

Installation for jar to exe/dmg.

Answer (score 0):

install4j does not convert a JAR files to an .exe file, it creates a native launcher for the JVM. The JAR file will be part of the installation directory and cannot be hidden.

To protect your class files, use an obfuscator like ProGuard. Any hiding of class files inside executables is pointless because it is easy to extract all classes from a running JVM.